# find -exec ; economy

Tags: find

If I'm scanning a large tree and want to pass results to another command before scanning the whole thing, will the ; option do this? From my reading, it seems to, but I want to be certain there's no background caching. If there is background caching, I want to know so I can use for loops instead.

When running find on a few files, there is no delay or strain on the disc. For a script that runs often, and on a long list of files, it can take minutes before find passes the full list to the next command. I want find to only run on one file at a time, and also refrain from searching the target until the previous -exec is completed.

Comment: Please expand on what you want to do and what you mean by _background caching_ (of what?) and in what context? The _scan lare tree_ and _pass results to a command_ followed by _before scanning_ doesn't make sense to me either.

Comment: Don't expand on your question in comments; edit the question to incorporate the new information.

Comment: Ok I put the comment in my question.

Comment: I think so, if that reduces wear on the file device.

Comment: @Lumify "reduces wear"? It feels like there's quite a lot of information missing from the question, especially what your concerns are and what the issue is.

Comment: How big is a "large" tree?

Comment: Like, big, dude.

Comment: What do you mean by "_I want find to only run on one file at a time_"? The command is intended to scan a filesystem tree, but it can only do they one for at a time.

Comment: Still waiting to find out what you mean by "_background caching_"?

Comment: "_Large tree_"... 100s? 1000s? 1,000,000s? More?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be asking whether

```
find -exec some_command '{}' \;
```

will execute `some_command` once for each file, sequentially, without doing anything else in the background while `some_command` is executing.

Indeed this is true.

However, you also seem to think that this would decrease wear on the hard drive.  This is probably not the case -- starting and stopping I/O lots of times requires more mechanical movements than reading lots of data at once, and so probably results in (*very* slightly) more wear on a traditional spinning hard drive.

Comment: I appreciate the illustration of the utilization of -exec

Answer (score 0):

You could try a bit different approach and use named pipes: [How to launch a pipe as a persistent process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369232/how-to-launch-a-pipe-as-a-persistent-process)

Basically:

1. Create a named pipe
2. Launch your process which you wanted to use in  find's -exec argument and have it read from pipe.
3. Launch the find process and have it write  the results to the pipe
4. From your process then you could control and stop find if you reach a result that means you don't need to list the rest of the
   files.